# handle errors in whiptail gauge with a msgbox

Tags: bash, whiptail

I am trying to run a whiptail `gauge` where I am showing progress as multiple commands are run. I have some error checking, but since the commands are running in a subshell, I can't seem to display the error in a `msgbox`. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Below is a sample of what I have tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{
   echo 0
   some_cmd1
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      whiptail --msgbox "error running cmd" 8 48
   fi
   echo 20
   some_cmd2
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      whiptail --msgbox "error running cmd" 8 48
   fi
   ...
   echo 100
} | whiptail --gauge "checking pre-reqs..." 8 48 0
```

I've also tried returning a status code, but I'm at a loss of how to utilize it if since it's being piped into whiptail

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{
   echo 0
   some_cmd1
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "error running cmd"
      return 1
   fi
   echo 20
   some_cmd2
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "error running cmd"
      return 1
   fi
   ...
   echo 100
} | whiptail --gauge "checking pre-reqs..." 8 48 0
```

Also, if I'm going about this wrong, please let me know as well!

Comment: Prefer  `if ! some_cmd2; do`. over `if [ $? -ne 0 ]`. I do not know - from the look of it, you have to stop whiptail, and display your error message. Is this what you want to intent?

Comment: thanks for the tip, I'll add it to my toolbox! As for the intent, yes, if an error occurs, I would like to essentially stop the gauge and display the error message instead, then handle the logic from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

myfunc() {
   echo 0

   sleep 1

   echo 20
   sleep 1
   if ! false; then
      whiptail --msgbox "error running cmd" 8 48 >&2
      return 1
   fi
   :
   echo 100
   sleep 1
}

myfunc | whiptail --gauge "checking pre-reqs..." 8 48 0
```